# Overwrite files with s3cmd

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd

I try to upload files to my S3 Bucket using the s3cmd. Works fine as it should, but files which already exist will not be overwritten but saved as a new file like "filename-1.ext".

I have found the

```
-f, --force (Force overwrite and other dangerous operations.)
```

command at http://s3tools.org/usage and tried

```
s3cmd put ~/Desktop/filename.ext  s3://mybucket -f
```

but files are still saved as new and not overwritten.
Does anyone have any idea? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have never seen s3cmd store an object with a new filename as you describe.  What version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

These days it is recommended to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

It has an `aws s3 cp` command that always retains the requested name.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the existing file first: `s3cmd del s3://bucket/file` then put the new file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mc (a.k.a. Minio client)](https://github.com/minio/mc). It’s written in Golang & available under the Open Source Apache License. It is available for Mac, Linux, Windows, and FreeBSD. You can use the `mc cp` command to achieve your requirement.

### mc GNU/Linux Download

```
64-bit Intel from https://dl.minio.io/client/mc/release/linux-amd64/mc
32-bit Intel from https://dl.minio.io/client/mc/release/linux-386/mc
32-bit ARM from https://dl.minio.io/client/mc/release/linux-arm/mc
$ chmod +x mc
$ ./mc --help
```

### Configuring mc for Amazon S3

```
$ mc config host add mys3 https://s3.amazonaws.com BKIKJAA5BMMU2RHO6IBB V7f1CwQqAcwo80UEIJEjc5gVQUSSx5ohQ9GSrr12
```

- Replace with your access/secret key.
- By default, mc uses signature version 4 of Amazon S3.
- mys3 is Amazon S3 alias for minio client.

**Overwrite your object name `myfile.txt`** to Amazon S3 bucket name `mybucket`

```
./mc cp myfile.txt mys3/mybucket
```

Hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I work for [Minio](https://minio.io)